# How to draw a cut image with a Width and Height c#

Tags: c#, image, canvas, cursor

I've been working on an engine for a while now and the cursor is to small so I'd like to know how to change the Height and Width. Here's the code I'm using.

```
    public void drawCutImage(int cutX, int cutY, int cutWidth, int cutHeight, int drawX, int drawY, Image image)
    {
        // Clone a portion of the Bitmap object.
        Rectangle sourceRect = new Rectangle(cutHeight * cutX, cutWidth * cutY, cutWidth, cutHeight);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat format =
            image.PixelFormat;

        // Draw the cloned portion of the Bitmap object.
        sCanvas.DrawImage(image, drawX, drawY, sourceRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
```

But i want to be able to do this

```
        sCanvas.DrawImage(image, drawX, drawY, drawWidth, drawHeight, sourceRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Comment: Try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms142040%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) format! It'll do just what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This link will be very helpful, please visit;
http://tech.pro/tutorial/620/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing

you can also use another way to cut image by cropping and cloning the image with specific starting points and size.

```
private static Image cropImage(Image img, Rectangle cropArea)
{
Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(img);
return bmpImage.Clone(cropArea, bmpImage.PixelFormat);
}
```

Hope this helps.